# AWS S3 filter by tags. search by tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, search, tags, aws-sdk

We have our bucket with new AWS SDK API on AWS S3. We uploaded and tagged lots of files and folders with tags.

How can we filter on key-value tag, or only one of them? I'd like to find all the objects with key = "temp", or key = "temp" and value = "lol".

Comment: I think that it is not possible '( I did it in a PS1 script retrieving all objects with Get-S3Object, then for each one Get-S3ObjectTagSet and filter result if ( ($tags | Where-Object {$_.Key -eq 'toDelete'}).Value -eq 'y' ). I'm trying it with PS 4.0, I don't know if in modern versions result of Get-S3Object could be pipelined

Comment: You need to specify whether you are talking about resource tags (a tag on a bucket which is the same type of tag you would apply to an ec2-instance or another resource) or whether you are talking about S3 Object Tagging which are two totally different things and your lack of detail is causing much confusion in the answers below https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-tagging.html

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I also hoped that AWS will eventually support "search files by tags" because that would open up possibilities like e.g. having a photo storage with the names, descriptions, location stored in tags so I wouldn't need a separate database.

But, apparently AWS explicitly is not supporting this, and will probably never do so. Quoting from their [storage service white paper](https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/Storage/AWS%20Storage%20Services%20Whitepaper-v9.pdf):

> Amazon S3 doesn’t suit all storage situations. [...] some storage needs for which you should consider other AWS storage options [...]
>
> Amazon S3 doesn’t offer query capabilities to retrieve specific objects. When you use Amazon S3 you need to know the exact bucket name and key for the files you want to retrieve from the service. Amazon S3 can’t be used as a database or search engine by itself.
>
> Instead, you can pair Amazon S3 with Amazon DynamoDB, Amazon CloudSearch, or Amazon Relational Database Service (Amazon RDS) to index and query metadata about Amazon S3 buckets and objects.

AWS suggests using DynamoDB, RDS or CloudSearch instead.

Comment: you might consider azure blob storage as a solution. It supports searching by tags on all access tiers (including archive). I'm considering it for my own photos as an archive solution.

Answer (score 7):

There seems to be one way to achieve what you're looking for, although it's not ideal, or particularly user-friendly.

The [AWS S3 tagging documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-tagging.html#tagging-other-configs) says that you can grant accounts permissions for objects with a given tag. If you created a new account with the right permissions then you could probably get the filtered list.

Not particularly useful on an ongoing basis, though.

Comment: AWS list or describe operations can't filter their result depending on the permissions. You can only restrict what arguments are passed to list operations at most.

Answer (score 5):

This is now possible using `AWS Resource Tagging API` and `S3 Select (SQL)`. See this post: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/architecture/how-to-efficiently-extract-and-query-tagged-resources-using-the-aws-resource-tagging-api-and-s3-select-sql/.

However, the Resource Tagging API supports only tags on buckets for the S3 service, not on objects: [New – AWS Resource Tagging API](https://aws.amazon.com/it/blogs/aws/new-aws-resource-tagging-api/)

Comment: You need to maintain a separate csv mapping s3 object <=> tags_list for this to work. The csv lives in S3 and is queried using S3 Select. This is an option but keeping the csv updated is an extra chore.

Answer (score 4):

AFAIK - Resource Groups don't support tags on an S3 Object level only on a bucket level.

Source: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-resource-tagging-api/ (scroll down the page to the table).

Comment: If you could add a source to this, it would greatly improve this answer! As it stands right now it looks more like an assumption which should go into a comment instead of a definitive answer.

Comment: I think that David Mc didn't have enough rep to add his information as a comment

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to filter/search by tags. But you can implement this yourself using S3.

You can create a special prefix in a bucket, e.g. /tags/. Then for each actual object you add and want to assign a tag (e.g. `Department=67`), you add a new object in /tags/, e.g: `/tags/XXXXXXXXX_YYYYYYYYY_ZZZZZZZZZ`, where

```
XXXXXXXXX = hash('Department')
YYYYYYYYY = hash('67')
ZZZZZZZZZ = actualObjectKey
```

Then when you want to get all objects that have a particular tag assigned (e.g. `Department`), you have to execute the ListObjectsV2 S3 API for prefix `/tags/XXXXXXXXX_`. If you want objects that have particular tag value (e.g. `Department=67`), you have to execute the ListObjectsV2 S3 API for prefix `/tags/XXXXXXXXX_YYYYYYYYY_`

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectsV2.html

It's not that fast but still does the job.

Obvious downside is that you have to remove the tags yourself. For example, you can do all of this above with a S3 triggers and lambda.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to query tags and values that you added 
using resource-groups/query resource:

```
https://${region}.console.aws.amazon.com/resource-groups/resources
```

Comment: You can use this to find S3 buckets, not objects within a bucket.

Answer (score 0):

There is many way to get filter list of s3 by tag. I used in my code:

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

def get_tag_value(tags, key):
    for tag in tags:
        if tag["Key"] == key:
            return tag["Value"]
    return ""

def filter_s3_by_tag_value(tag_key,tag_value):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    response = s3.list_buckets()
    s3_list=[]
    for bucket in response["Buckets"]:
        try:
            response_tags = s3.get_bucket_tagging(Bucket=bucket["Name"])  
            if get_tag_value(response_tags["TagSet"],tag_key) == tag_value: 
                s3_list.append(bucket["Name"])
        except ClientError as e:
            print(e.response["Error"]["Code"]) 

    return s3_list     

def filter_s3_by_tag_key(tag_key):
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    response = s3.list_buckets()
    s3_list=[]
    for bucket in response["Buckets"]:
        try:
            response_tags = s3.get_bucket_tagging(Bucket=bucket["Name"])  
            if get_tag_value(response_tags["TagSet"],tag_key) != "": 
                s3_list.append(bucket["Name"])
        except ClientError as e:
            print(e.response["Error"]["Code"]) 

    return s3_list     



print(filter_s3_by_tag_value(tag_key,tag_value))    

print(filter_s3_by_tag_key(tag_key))
```

Answer (score -7):

AWS now supports tagging of S3 images.

They have APIs to add/remove tags.

Amazon S3 Select, Amazon Athena can be used to search for S3 resources with TAGS.

Currently the max number of tags per resource is 10 (thanks Kyle Bridenstine for pointing out the correct number).

Comment: Where are you getting this information from because it's not in that link you pasted. You can only apply 10 tags per S3 Object and as far as I can tell you cannot use AWS Athena to query by S3 Object Tags. Please prove me wrong though because I desperately want the ability to query by tags...

Comment: My bad. I must have looked at the wrong kind of AWS object with a cap of 50. Yes, you are correct, currently it is max 10 for S3 objects. 

However, there are some good implementations with AWS ElasticSearch + DynamoDB that let u query images. Here is one:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/indexing-metadata-in-amazon-elasticsearch-service-using-aws-lambda-and-python/

I currently save my TAGS as EXIF data within the image before I upload it to S3, and build indexing / search functionality around that.

Comment: Okay so take down your wrong answer or modify it... Using ElasticSearch and DynamoDB isn't what the user asked for either.