# AWS CLI s3 cp: How to exclude objects by tags?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

I use following command to copy all files from bucket to another:

```
aws s3 cp s3://source_bucket s3://target_bucket --recursive
```

How to exclude files from source which have some tag in metadata (e.g. "Flag=1")?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Aws S3 Filter by Tags. Search by tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41571309/aws-s3-filter-by-tags-search-by-tags)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to specify tags as part of an AWS CLI `aws s3 cp` command.

It's actually pretty hard to use tags on S3 objects because they are not included in bucket listings. You actually need to retrieve tags on each object individually, which makes it too much of a pain to use.

Sometimes putting objects into specific folders is a good workaround.