# How to get objects with given tag in given S3 bucket?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using [@aws-sdk/client-s3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@aws-sdk/client-s3) and can’t figure out how to get objects with given tag in given S3 bucket.

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41571309/aws-s3-filter-by-tags-search-by-tags, it is not possible.

Comment: if you name your objects with a prefix (the tag) you can filter using https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#listObjects-property using the Prefix property